# найти любой набор целых чисел a1, a2, …, ak (1 ≤ ai < n) такой, что выполняется равенство

Tags: python, алгоритм

Вам дано число `n`. Необходимо найти любой набор целых чисел a1, a2, …, ak (1 ≤ ai < `n`) такой, что выполняется равенство: [image: Формула]

Если такого набора не существует, то нужно вывести `-1`.

---

Если существует набор целых чисел a1, …, ak, удовлетворяющий условиям, то выведите его в сжатом формате, а именно

- в первой строке выведите количество различных чисел m (1 ≤ m ≤ 10^5) в наборе. Можно показать, что если ответ существует, то различных чисел в нём не больше 10^5.
- В следующих m строках выведите пару чисел xi pi (1 ≤ xi < n, 1 ≤ pi ≤ n) — элемент из последовательности и количество его вхождений соответственно.
  Если подходящего набора не существует, то в единственной строке выведите -1.

***Пример теста:***

```
Ввод    Вывод
24
        3
        2 1
        12 1
        1 10


19     -1
```

Comment: Ну так если число делится на какие-то два множителя, большие 1 - все, сумму добиваем единицами... Ну, например, 18: 6*3, значит, 6, 3, и девять единиц... Такое решение годится? На `k` ведь никаких ограничений?

Comment: Вероятно, все числа должны быть разными? Не могу распарсить «Вывод»)

Comment: @vp_arth я вот тоже никак не пойму что это за вывод такой. ни общая сумма ни построчная ни произведения не равны 24

Comment: Нашёл дополнение к выводу) В общем, это 2, 12 и 10 единиц

Comment: @vp_arth Так что, я таки был прав? :)

Answer (score 3):

Если число делится на какие-то два множителя, большие 1 - все, сумму добиваем единицами...

```
n = int(input())

i = 2
count = 0
m = [0,0,0]
c = [0,0,0]
while i*i <= n:
    if n%i == 0:
        if i*i == n:
            m[count] = i
            c[count] = 2
            count += 1
        else:
            m[count] = i
            c[count] = 1
            count += 1
            m[count] = n//i
            c[count] = 1
            count += 1
        if n//i+i != n:
            m[count] = 1
            c[count] = n - n//i - i
            count += 1
        break
    else:
        i += 1

if i*i > n: print(-1)
else:
    print(count)
    for i in range(count):
        print(m[i],c[i])
```

Comment: @vp_arth Логично, спасибо.

Comment: А теперь не хватает вывода 3/2/1 =) Первая строка вывода - количество уникальных чисел)

Comment: @vp_arth "Ну просто хочется рвать и метать!" (с)

Comment: =) Ещё бы) И так сойдёт)

Comment: @vp_arth Беда в том, что для меня python - темна вода во облацех... Так что, наверное, настоящих питонщиков должно от этого кода просто мутить :)

Comment: Ну да, надо было в словарь собирать)